# Summing column values with condition on a new column

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Letter  Item1  Item2
'a'     2      3
'b'     3      5
'c'     6      7
```

How can I write a query returning sum of items for words I pass if the word contains certain letters? For example:

```
Word  Sum
'ab'  13
'abc' 26
'bc'  21
```

Edit: I need to pass several words in the query.

Comment: Why would you not consider `ca` or `ac` ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

`SELECT [enter word] AS Word, Sum(IIf(InStr([enter word],[Letter])>0,[Item1]+[Item2],0)) AS LtrSum FROM Table1 GROUP BY [enter word];`

or

`SELECT DISTINCT [enter word1] AS W1, Sum(IIf(InStr([enter word1],[Letter])>0,[Item1]+[Item2],0)) AS C1, [enter word2] AS W2, Sum(IIf(InStr([enter word2],[Letter])>0,[Item1]+[Item2],0)) AS C2, [enter word3] AS W3, Sum(IIf(InStr([enter word3],[Letter])>0,[Item1]+[Item2],0)) AS C3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [enter word1], [enter word2], [enter word3];`

or

`SELECT DISTINCT [enter word1] AS W1, DSum("Item1","Table1","InStr('" & [enter word1] & "', [Letter])>0")+DSum("Item2","Table1","InStr('" & [enter word1] & "', [Letter])>0") AS C1, [enter word2] AS W2, DSum("Item1","Table1","InStr('" & [enter word2] & "', [Letter])>0")+DSum("Item2","Table1","InStr('" & [enter word2] & "', [Letter])>0") AS C2, [enter word3] AS W3, DSum("Item1","Table1","InStr('" & [enter word3] & "', [Letter])>0")+DSum("Item2","Table1","InStr('" & [enter word3] & "', [Letter])>0") AS C3
FROM Table1;`

or

`SELECT Table2.Word, Sum(IIf(InStr([Word],[Letter])>0,[Item1]+[Item2],0)) AS LtrSum
FROM Table2, Table1
GROUP BY Table2.Word;`

Comment: Thanks. But what if I need to pass, say, 5 words in the query and they are not stored in another table?

Comment: see revised answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql):

```
SELECT SUM(Item1) + SUM(Item2)
FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CHARINDEX(Letter, ENTER_WORD) > 0
```

Comment: CharIndex is not a recognized function in Access query.